# XSLT 1.0 Logic on nodes

Tags: xslt

equal nodes should comes under the single counter element.
input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

For each pack number we need to increment the counter variable, but here one condition is present like if previous  is equal to current  we have to ignore the counter (there is no need to increment) like below output.all the equal nodes comes under one counter like below output.

The XSLT template should contain `<for-each>` like below structure.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <A>
    <target>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Move-Afile/Afile/Item/PACK050/PackNumber">

        <xsl:variable name="count">
          <!-- get the count here-->
        </xsl:variable>

        <counter>$count</counter>
        <PNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></PNumber>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </target>
  </A>
</xsl:template>
```

output:

```
<A>
  <target>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <counter>1</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item
    <PACK050>
      <counter>2</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is  equal to current <PackNumber> ignore the counter -->
      <PACK050>
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is  equal to current <PackNumber> ignore the counter -->
      <PACK050>
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <PACK050>
      <counter>3</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>126</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>

  </target>
</A>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of it as incrementing a counter, think of it as grouping similar nodes.  What you're trying to do here is to group the `Item` elements by their `PackNumber`, and then for each group write out the first matching `Item` with a `counter` value and the rest without.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="itemByPnum" match="Item" use="PACK050/PackNumber" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <A>
      <target>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Move-Afile/Afile/Item[generate-id() =
             generate-id(key('itemByPnum', PACK050/PackNumber)[1])]" />
      </target>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="counter">
        <counter><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></counter>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- copy without the <counter> all matching Items except the first one -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
          select="key('itemByPnum', PACK050/PackNumber)
          [generate-id() != generate-id(current())]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="counter" />
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$counter" />
        <PNumber><xsl:value-of select="PACK050/PackNumber" /></PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is an example of a technique called Muenchian grouping.  The initial `apply-templates` in the `/` template extracts the *first* `Item` with each `PackNumber`, the `Item` template then generates the right output for that group.

Comment: +1 I was a little sloppy in my answer; yours is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can actually be solved by using the well-known Muenchian Grouping methodology for XSLT 1.0.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kItemByPackNo" match="Item" use="*/PackNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <A>
      <target>
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="*/Item[generate-id() = 
                         generate-id(key('kItemByPackNo', */PackNumber)[1])]"/>
      </target>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <Item>
      <counter>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </counter>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Item>
    <xsl:copy-of
      select="key('kItemByPackNo', */PackNumber)[
                not(generate-id() = generate-id(current()))
              ]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PackNumber">
    <PNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PNumber>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
<A>
  <target>
    <Item>
      <counter>1</counter>
      <PACK050>
        <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <counter>2</counter>
      <PACK050>
        <PNumber>567</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PACK050>
        <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <counter>3</counter>
      <PACK050>
        <PNumber>126</PNumber>
      </PACK050>
    </Item>
  </target>
</A>
```